# Why is the map $\gamma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $\gamma(t)=(t^3,0)$ is a smooth embedding because $\gamma'(0)=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

From *Intro to Smooth Manifolds* by Lee:

> The map $\gamma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $\gamma(t)=(t^3,0)$ is smooth and a topological embedding, but it is not a smooth embedding because $\gamma'(0)=0$.

I know this map is not a smooth embedding because it is a not an immersion since $\gamma'(t)=(3t^2,0)$ and thus $\gamma'(1)=\gamma'(-1)$ and hence the derivative is not injective.

**How does $\gamma'(0)=0$ imply that the map is not a smooth immersion?**

Comment: Because the vanishing of the derivative tells you that the differential is not injective there and hence the whole thing is not an immersion.

Comment: How does the vanishing of the derivative imply that?

Comment: Wait, I don’t think an immersion requires the derivative to be injective. $\gamma(t)=(t,0)$ should be an immersion, for example...

Comment: A smooth map $F:M \to N$ is called a smooth immersion if its differential $dF_p$ is injective at every point $p \in M$. Doesn't this mean that it's derivative is injective at every point?

Comment: For all $t$, in standard coordinates the tangent map $T_t \Bbb R \to T_t \Bbb R^2$ has matrix representation $d\gamma_t = \gamma'(t) = \pmatrix{3 t^2\\0}$. At $t = 0$, the tangent map is zero and so not injective.

Comment: There's an additional confusion here: The quantities $\gamma'(\pm 1)$ are not equal, and in fact aren't even comparable, as they live in two different tangent spaces, namely, $T_{(\pm 1, 0)} \Bbb R^2$, respectively. It's true that in standard coordinates the identifications of these tangent maps with elements of $\Bbb R^{2 \times 1}$ agree, but that's (1) not intrinsically geometric, as it depends on a choice of coordinates (2) anyway not what is specified in the definition of immersion.

Comment: You need the derivative to have constant rank equal to $\mathbb{R}$, thus you need $\operatorname {rank} D_p \gamma = 1$ to suffice for every $p \in \mathbb{R}$ which is not the case for $p = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding [Travis'](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155629/travis) comment, at any point $t$, the differential of $\gamma$ is $d\gamma_t: T_t \mathbb R \to T_{\gamma(t)} \mathbb R^2$ defined as
$$\begin{align*}
\gamma'(t)&=d\gamma_t\left(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_t\right)\\
&=\frac{d\gamma^1}{dt}(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}+\frac{d\gamma^2}{dt}(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}\\
&=3t^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}+ 0 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_{\gamma(t)}
\end{align*}.$$

So, the matrix of $d\gamma_t$ is 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3t^2 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

When $t=0$, the differential $d\gamma_0$ is the zero transformation which is not injective. So, $\gamma$ is not a smooth immersion.

Comment: isn't the matrix of $d\gamma_t$ supposed to be $\begin{pmatrix} 3t^2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @Zest Yes. Good catch.

Comment: @AlJebr "When t=0, the differential $dγ_0$ is the zero transformation which is not injective. So, γ is not a smooth immersion." Why is that the case?